# weak homotopy equivalence of simplicial sets are quasi-isomorphisms

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I'm trying to prove that a weak equivalence $f: X \rightarrow Y$ of simplicial sets induces a quasi-isomoprhism $Z[X] \rightarrow Z[Y]$ where $Z[X]$ is the chain complex of free abelian groups of $X_n$.

Any solution or reference would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of weak equivalence of simplicial sets and what do you know about them?

Comment: This follows pretty much directly from the Dold–Kan correspondence theorem.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Could you elaborate on this?